# Can PhoneGap show my web-based application as a embedded browser?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am creating a web application for desktops, tablets and smartphones. My application renders in server side (with asp.net mvc), and it'll be difficult to provide Ajax calls for every page...

Since I'm using JQuery mobile for generating ui, the ui of my program will be responsive even if it completely loads from server.

My first question is, can I load that webpage (which optimized for mobiles and tablets) in PhoneGap, like and embedded browser?

And I need to have some animation while downloading the first page, for better user experience and avoid app store submission problems. How to do this?

Comment: I guess that you can, but check whether you can submit such app to store.

Comment: @nhahtdh So where should I learn more about rules of submitting apps to app store and andorid market? Also how to do that in PhoneGap?

Comment: I don't know. I only heard about the case with Apple where an app without the skeleton HTML is rejected, out of the concern that the actual content served is changed after the app is in the store. Not sure about Android market.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about making an iframe with...

```
iframe { width: 100%, height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; z-index: 1; }
```

Then make a div for your animation with the following style...

```
#animation { width: 100%, height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; z-index: 2; }
```

Then add something like this

```
myIFRAME.document.onload = $('#animation').hide();
```

---

However you always have to be online and you will feel a slow connection in the responsiveness of your "app".

Here is a bit more information on how native applications are usually a bit faster then HTML5 based. Your's will be even worse because it's an html5 app embedded within an html5 app... https://stackoverflow.com/a/10772161/773263

0% chance of getting into iTunes.

Android will be fine

Comment: What do you mean about `you will feel a slow connection in the responsiveness of your "app"`? Do you mean *waiting times* or  *transitions* or other thing?

Comment: I've made a bit of an edit with a link to an explanation why HTML apps can be slower... which in your case will be even worse because it's an html app with an iframe... double whammy.

Comment: Isn't there any way other than an `iframe`? for example a code in downloaded page that shows a *loading...* immediately.

Comment: As far as I know, especially for iPhone your first page must be local like a menu or item and you can redirect the page you want from there. You should also check if there is a connection or error and display a message if needed.

Comment: jQuery page preloading feature can help improve responsiveness of app, and since my project is a news reader, a little slowness is usual I think. So, also with note that OnurTOPAL said, isn't there still any chance to getting into iTunes?

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi There are other ways to do it but they all have the same under lying problem which is... the code is not packaged within the app itself.

Comment: @PhilipK There are many other applications with PhoneGap that just an ajax loader, and data is downloading from outside...

Comment: So what is the best method for me to getting into iTunes?

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi Yes I have built such apps but you specified in your question that you did not want to do that.

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi Your not going to get it into iTunes unless you include some kind of native feature: e.g. camera, accelerometer, ect.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15379/discussion-between-mahdi-ghiasi-and-philipk)

Comment: See my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973470/will-apple-app-store-accept-an-application-that-uses-uiwebview-for-almost-everyt